# python using for loop to update nested dictionary values with comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested, dictionary-comprehension

i am struggling with this for loop.  I want to update the nested dictionary's value with the list.  the following works, but I would like to use for loop to condense the code.  `"status"` is a nested dictionary that has outer key `"A"` and `"B"`, and `binary_list[]` just all 1's.

```
Trucks = ["A", "B"]
Days= ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",    
"Saturday", "Sunday"]

requests={"A": {"Monday":0, "Tuesday":0, "Wednesday":0, "Thursday":0     
                "Friday":0, "Saturday":0, "Sunday":0},
          "B": {"Monday":0, "Tuesday":0, "Wednesday":0, "Thursday":0,    
                "Friday":0, "Saturday":0, "Sunday":0}}


binary_list=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]



status["A"]["Monday"]=binary_list[0]
status["A"]["Tuesday"]=binary_list[1]
status["A"]["Wednesday"]=binary_list[2]
status["A"]["Thursday"]=binary_list[3]
status["A"]["Friday"]=binary_list[4]
status["A"]["Saturday"]=binary_list[5]
status["A"]["Sunday"]=binary_list[6]

status["B"]["Monday"]=binary_list[7]
status["B"]["Tuesday"]=binary_list[8]
status["B"]["Wednesday"]=binary_list[9]
status["B"]["Thursday"]=binary_list[10]
status["B"]["Friday"]=binary_list[11]
status["B"]["Saturday"]=binary_list[12]
status["B"]["Sunday"]=binary_list[13]
```

what I tried:

```
   for truck in Trucks:
        for day in Days:
            requests[truck][day]=[j for j in binary_list]
```

this will produce 14 1's in a list as the value of each of the day.  I understand why this happens.  it's because of the 2 for loops, so I figured I need a nested dictionary comprehenssions to make everything into one line.  I am not sure that is correct, but with my limited knowledge that seems to be the right direction.  my questions is how do I do that? would someone please help.  thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an iterator to iterate through the values of `binary_list` instead:

```
iter_binary_list = iter(binary_list)
for truck in Trucks:
    for day in Days:
        requests[truck][day] = next(iter_binary_list)
```

Comment: thank you blhsing, imtinan Azhar, sinwoobang moe A.  I was able to read more on iter to learn more about your solution.  I really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary comprehension to do it in a one liner and more "pythonic" way as the following:

```
it = iter(binary_list)
status = {x: {d: next(it) for d in Days} for x in Trucks}
# outputs: {'A': {'Monday': 1, 'Tuesday': 1, 'Wednesday': 1, 'Thursday': 1, 'Friday': 1, 'Saturday': 1, 'Sunday': 1}, 'B': {'Monday': 1, 'Tuesday': 1, 'Wednesday': 1, 'Thursday': 1, 'Friday': 1, 'Saturday': 1, 'Sunday': 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is wrong, j for j in binary_list] will create a list for each requests[truck][day] and this is not what you want, what you want is something like this

```
binary_list_iterator=0

for truck in Trucks:
    for day in Days:
        requests[truck][day]=binary_list[binary_list_iterator]
        binary_list_iterator+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

`requests = {t: {d: 1 for d in Days} for t in Trucks}`

Or if you want to iterate everything

`requests = {t: {d: binary_list[i*len(Days)+j] for j, d in enumerate(Days)} for i, t in enumerate(Trucks)}`